# Angular directive for validation using two models

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

Using the new $validators object on ngModel, I want to validate an input field based upon the data in the input field in addition to a checkbox. The directive works great if the checkbox is (un)checked prior to user input, but if the user is done inputting and then clicks on the checkbox, no validation occurs.

Is there a way to trigger the validation if either the checkbox or the input field changes?

Code looks like:

```
app.directive('denyMultiples', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      denyMultipleCheck: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.multiples = function(value) {
        if(!Array.isArray(value)) {
          value = value.split(',');
        }
        return value.length < 2 || !scope.denyMultipleCheck;
      };
    }
  };
});
// HTML
<input name="items" deny-multiples deny-multiples-check="query.deny_multiples_check" ng-model="items">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using ng-required to determine if the validator should be run or not

```
<input name="items" deny-multiples deny-multiples-check="query.deny_multiples_check" ng-required="query.deny_multiples_check" ng-model="items">
```

When the checkbox is checked, then the $validator will be run. Otherwise the check is ignored.